How to make concurrently not kill my NextJS front when the FastAPI back restart
I have a FastAPI NextJS webapp on which I use concurrently to have both on the same terminal.
The issue is that when I change the backend, it restarts and kills my front.
What can I do to have them both running on one command with both apps debug on the same terminal without having to restart everything everytime I change the back.
In my package.json:
"fastapi-dev": "cd ../backend && pipenv run python -m uvicorn main:app --reload --port 3030",
"next-dev": "next dev",
"dev": "concurrently \"pnpm run next-dev\" \"pnpm run fastapi-dev\"",

I tried adding --no-kill-others or --raw --restart-tries 3 without success, whenever the back restart it just kills the front.
Best, R.
